# Crude hidden line removal for oscilloscope output

Tags: python, normals

I am currently expermenting with some real ancient display method. Vector displays. I am using a Teensy Microprocessor (very like an Arduino but faster) and can actually display Blenders 3D Viewport as vector graphics on my scope. See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6yvyGDUoXU

I am now searching for a crude hidden line algo, but due to my limited math and cgx knowledge this is hard :-) "crude" means I tend to do it the "Elite" (game) on a C64, which uses some kind of per object line removal: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltsqeUbPuEM

I think I can use the vertex normals for this? Some dotproduct of normal and view vector?

Or are there some hidden treasures inside Blender which help me? I *think* it would also be too slow to do real hidden line, maybe a good pythoneer can optimize it, but... :-) The code has also other issues, I did stole quite a lot from different examples. On my laptop I can output a Suzanne at 15fps. The scope is real analogue, so I can't give here exact values, at some point it starts to flicker as the teensy tries to maintain equal brightness for the lines.

```
# Blender2v scope/vectrex output. 
# c.wartmann@gmx.net
import time
import sys
import serial

import bpy
import bpy_extras

class SerHandle(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sock = serial.Serial('COM12', 9600,timeout=5)
#        self.sock=None
        self.scene = bpy.context.scene
        self.cam = bpy.data.objects.get("Camera")
        if self.cam == None:
            print("No Camera")
            exit

    def __del__(self):
        # why is it not called automatically?
        print("Closing Serial!!!!!")
        self.sock.close()

    '''
     forked from https://bitbucket.org/marcusva/py-sdl2 (which has public-domain license)
     The MIT License (MIT)
     Copyright (c) 2014 Michael Hirsch
     reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Sutherland_algorithm
     * I have corrected errors in the cohensutherland code and compared cohensutherland with Matlab polyxpoly() results.
     * The best way to Numba JIT this would probably be in the function calling this, to include the loop itself
       inside the jit decoration.
    '''
    #@jit
    def cohensutherland(self, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        """Clips a line to a rectangular area.
        This implements the Cohen-Sutherland line clipping algorithm.  xmin,
        ymax, xmax and ymin denote the clipping area, into which the line
        defined by x1, y1 (start point) and x2, y2 (end point) will be
        clipped.
        If the line does not intersect with the rectangular clipping area,
        four None values will be returned as tuple. Otherwise a tuple of the
        clipped line points will be returned in the form (cx1, cy1, cx2, cy2).
        """
        INSIDE,LEFT, RIGHT, LOWER, UPPER = 0,1, 2, 4, 8

        def _getclip(xa, ya):
            p = INSIDE  #default is inside

            # consider x
            if xa < xmin:
                p |= LEFT
            elif xa > xmax:
                p |= RIGHT

            # consider y
            if ya < ymin:
                p |= LOWER # bitwise OR
            elif ya > ymax:
                p |= UPPER #bitwise OR
            return p

    # check for trivially outside lines
        k1 = _getclip(x1, y1)
        k2 = _getclip(x2, y2)

    #%% examine non-trivially outside points
        #bitwise OR |
        while (k1 | k2) != 0: # if both points are inside box (0000) , ACCEPT trivial whole line in box

            # if line trivially outside window, REJECT
            if (k1 & k2) != 0: #bitwise AND &
                 return None, None, None, None

            #non-trivial case, at least one point outside window
            # this is not a bitwise or, it's the word "or"
            opt = k1 or k2 # take first non-zero point, short circuit logic
            if opt & UPPER:
                x = x1 + (x2 - x1) * (ymax - y1) / (y2 - y1)
                y = ymax
            elif opt & LOWER:
                x = x1 + (x2 - x1) * (ymin - y1) / (y2 - y1)
                y = ymin
            elif opt & RIGHT:
                y = y1 + (y2 - y1) * (xmax - x1) / (x2 - x1)
                x = xmax
            elif opt & LEFT:
                y = y1 + (y2 - y1) * (xmin - x1) / (x2 - x1)
                x = xmin
            else:
                raise RuntimeError('Undefined clipping state')
            if opt == k1:
                x1, y1 = x, y
                k1 = _getclip(x1, y1)
            elif opt == k2:
                x2, y2 = x, y
                k2 = _getclip(x2, y2)
        return x1, y1, x2, y2

    def send2v(self):
        vbytes = bytearray(4)
        for ob in bpy.context.visible_objects:
            if (ob.type in ['MESH']):
                me = ob.data
                wx = ob.location.x
                wy = ob.location.y
                mat = ob.matrix_world
                verts = ob.data.vertices
                edges = me.edges
                for ed in edges:
                    print(mat*verts[ed.vertices[0]].normal)
                    v0_2d = bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view(
                                    self.scene, self.cam, mat*verts[ed.vertices[0]].co)
                    v1_2d = bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view(
                                    self.scene, self.cam, mat*verts[ed.vertices[1]].co)
                    render_scale = self.scene.render.resolution_percentage / 100
                    render_size = (int(self.scene.render.resolution_x * render_scale),
                                   int(self.scene.render.resolution_y * render_scale))
                    x0=(v0_2d.x * render_size[0]) 
                    y0=(v0_2d.y * render_size[1]) 
                    x1=(v1_2d.x * render_size[0]) 
                    y1=(v1_2d.y * render_size[1])
                    x0,y0,x1,y1=self.cohensutherland(0,0,render_size[0]-1,
                                                         render_size[1]-1,x0,y0,x1,y1)
                    if (x0!=None):
                        v  = (1) << 30 | (0 & 63) << 24 | (round(x0) & 4095) << 12 | (round(y0) & 4095) << 0
                        vbytes.append((v >> 24) & 0xFF)
                        vbytes.append((v >> 16) & 0xFF)
                        vbytes.append((v >>  8) & 0xFF)
                        vbytes.append((v >>  0) & 0xFF)
                        v  = (1) << 30 | (1 & 63) << 24 | (round(x1) & 4095) << 12 | (round(y1) & 4095) << 0
                        vbytes.append((v >> 24) & 0xFF)
                        vbytes.append((v >> 16) & 0xFF)
                        vbytes.append((v >>  8) & 0xFF)
                        vbytes.append((v >>  0) & 0xFF)


        vbytes.append(1)
        vbytes.append(1)
        vbytes.append(1)
        vbytes.append(1)
        self.sock.write(vbytes)
#        time.sleep(0.1)


print("-------------------------------")
handle=SerHandle()
handle.send2v()
# not called automatically?
#del handle

def scene_update(context):
        objects = bpy.data.objects
        if objects.is_updated:
 #           print("update")
            handle.send2v()





bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post.append(scene_update)

# I wonder how to stop/remove the handler?
#bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post.remove(scene_update)
```

Comment: I can't seem to calculate the angle between vertex normal and the cam view correctly. I am lost, tired to get my head around some example of similar scripts but... Must me something like get vector from cam to vertex, then dot this to get a number...

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way to do hidden line removal in Blender Cycles a while back. I know nothing of Python, yet I do not believe it is necessary to resolve your issue. This is my test render with two cubes:

[image]

### Defining Geometry

The geometry in this scene is actually quite simple. I added two cubes. The larger one, moving diagonally is in front of the smaller one; it's not a difference in scale.

### Creating the Modifiers

For this render, we will use the *Wireframe Modifier*.

[image]

The *Thickness* is how thick the black lines will eventually be. The higher the number, the more thick. It is very important that you also set the *Material Offset* to 1 because even though it doesn't look like it, there is a material in the center of the cubes where the lines are not. Additionally, the *Material Offset* allows the wireframe to be different (black) than the 'Invisible' part. It is also important that you uncheck *Replace Original*. This means that the wire is added, rather than replacing the whole cube. The other check boxes have varying affects and are not needed.

### Adding Materials

Materials are everything.

- Begin by clicking the *New* button and setting the shader to *Holdout*. If you have done it right, the preview sphere will be totally black. We will change this to white later. The beauty of the holdout shader is it effectively punches a hole in your render the shape of your mesh. If you render now, your cubes will be totally black.
- Now click the plus button on the upper right hand side of the materials panel. Leave the *Diffuse BSDF* and set the color to dead black. Now your object will have two materials: One a holdout, for the center, and one a black line color. Because of the *Material Offset* we set up earlier, the wireframe modifier will use the black material giving the appearance of a cube with none of the hidden lines showing!

### Compositing

So great! If you click the render button now, you should have...two totally black cubes imposed on a grey background, which bears no resemblance to the earlier gif. This is because we still need to do some compositing. First, check *Transparent* under the *Film* section of the *Properties* panel.

[image]

Now if you render, you will notice that the grey background is gone, as is the inside of the cube. There is the real 'hole punching' that it does. For the nodes, go to the *Compositing* Screen layout found in the *Info* panel at the top of the screen. Select the *Compositing nodes* node tree type to display and edit. Also check *Use Nodes*. Both options are found on the bottom settings layer of the *Node Editor* panel, front and center in the
*Compositing* Screen layout. A *Render Layers* input and a *Composite* output node will appear. Move the mouse over the Node editor, key <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, mouse over to *Color*, and select *Alpha Over*. This new node will follow the mouse. Drag it over on top of the line connecting the first two nodes until the line glows orange. Then left click to confirm. Make sure the line connecting the yellow *Image* output of the *Render Layers* node is connected to the **bottom** yellow *Image* input of the *Alpha Over* node. Check that the remaining color is pure white, the *Fac* is 1, the *Premul* is 0, and the *Convert Premul* checkbox is unchecked. The node setup should look like this:

[image]

If you have done everything right, you have now hidden the back lines. You can keyframe the location of the boxes if you so desire to to make them move.

### Closing Thoughts

I chose to go with black and white, but you could play with the second material down to change the line color and the first material if you wanted to change the color inside the box. For a flat color, I would suggest using an *Emission* shader, set to the desired color. Obviously the *Alpha Over* color can also be changed to differ the background. If you wanted to see through to the other side of the box, you could use a *Transparent BSDF* set to pure white instead of the holdout. Lastly, consider [this tutorial](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-make-a-wireframe-render/) on the basics of the Wireframe Modifier and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOzfJBVMgPY) on the holdout shader. These are the only references I used when making this.

Hope this helps and happy Blending!

Comment: This is nice but was not the question.

Comment: I was answering based on the "Or are there some hidden treasures inside Blender which help me? I think it would also be too slow to do real hidden line, maybe a good pythoneer can optimize it, but... :-)" in your question. I am sorry if this wasn't what you were looking for.